# OpenCV Android wrong front camera orientation

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I'm trying to get the front camera using OpenCV 3.1 or even 2.4.11, stay with the correct orientation of the device and the image is not blurred (stretched) or have any other problem that harms the correct function of viewing!
I checked various means in other posts and none of them work or have a correct and functional effect!

Some attempts, but there are many others that do not work on the Internet!

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669779/opencv-camera-orientation-issue)

[link 2](http://answers.opencv.org/question/21964/android-camera-opens-in-landscape-mode-orientation-for-front-camera-in-opencvjavacv/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I made some workaround for this. I locked screen to portrait mode. It's not perfect but better than nothing.

**activity_main.xml**

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

and after **onCreate** method in Your activity

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```