# "JavaCameraView" Camera Orientation Issue

Tags: android, opencv

I am new to Android development. I'm making a simple app, which has one Activity. In this Activity I'm trying to get frames from camera and process it real time, but I'm having camera orientation Issue, i.e. image received is 90 degree rotated. There are many solutions available to solve this problem but found no one for the "JavaCameraView". So please help me out how to solve the orientation issue only for "JavaCameraView".

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
JavaCameraView javaCameraView;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                javaCameraView.enableView();
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    //}

    javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (javaCameraView != null)
        javaCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (javaCameraView != null)
        javaCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully.");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded.");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    frame = new Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4);


}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    frame.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    frame = inputFrame.rgba();
    //frame=processFrame();
    //Imgcodecs.imwrite("/storage/emulated/0/aaaaa+.jpg", frame);
    return frame;

}
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this [opencv orientation issue answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669779/opencv-camera-orientation-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solve this issue : 
Use below class instead of javaCameraView :

```
       public class PortraitCameraView extends CameraBridgeViewBase implements Camera.PreviewCallback {

private static final int MAGIC_TEXTURE_ID = 10;
private static final String TAG = "JavaCameraView";

private byte mBuffer[];
private Mat[] mFrameChain;
private int mChainIdx = 0;
private Thread mThread;
private boolean mStopThread;

public Camera mCamera;
protected JavaCameraFrame[] mCameraFrame;
private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture;
private int mCameraId;
Handler handler;
boolean callBuffer = false;
Camera.Size bestSize = null;
Camera.Size pictureSize = null;
private LayoutMode mLayoutMode;
private int mCenterPosX = -1;
private int mCenterPosY;

public static enum LayoutMode {
    FitToParent, // Scale to the size that no side is larger than the parent
    NoBlank // Scale to the size that no side is smaller than the parent
}

public static class JavaCameraSizeAccessor implements ListItemAccessor {

    public int getWidth(Object obj) {
        Camera.Size size = (Camera.Size) obj;
        return size.width;
    }

    public int getHeight(Object obj) {
        Camera.Size size = (Camera.Size) obj;
        return size.height;
    }
}

public PortraitCameraView(Context context, int cameraId) {
    super(context, cameraId);
}

public PortraitCameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected boolean initializeCamera(int width, int height) {

    handler = new Handler();
    Log.d(TAG, "Initialize java camera");
    boolean result = true;
    synchronized (this) {
        mCamera = null;

        boolean connected = false;
        int numberOfCameras = android.hardware.Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                try {
                    mCamera = Camera.open(i);
                    mCameraId = i;
                    connected = true;
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera #" + i + "failed to open: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                if (connected) break;
            }
        }

        if (mCamera == null) return false;

    /* Now set camera parameters */
        try {
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            List<Camera.Size> Picturesizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            pictureSize = Picturesizes.get(0);

            List<Camera.Size> sizeList = sizes;
            bestSize = sizeList.get(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "getSupportedPreviewSizes()  " + bestSize.width + "  " + bestSize.height);
            Log.d(TAG, "Picturesizes()  " + pictureSize.width + "  " + pictureSize.height);

       //                bestSize.width = GlobalArea.display_width;
     ////                bestSize.height = GlobalArea.display_height;
            for (int i = 1; i < sizeList.size(); i++) {

                if ((sizeList.get(i).width * sizeList.get(i).height) > (bestSize.width * bestSize.height)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getSupportedPreviewSizes()   " + sizeList.get(i).width + "  " + sizeList.get(i).height);
                    bestSize = sizeList.get(i);
                }
            }


            if (sizes != null) {
            /* Select the size that fits surface considering maximum size allowed */
                Size frameSize = calculateCameraFrameSize(sizes, new JavaCameraSizeAccessor(), height, width); //use turn around values here to get the correct prev size for portrait mode

                params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
                Log.e(TAG, "Set preview size to " + Integer.valueOf((int) bestSize.width) + " x " + Integer.valueOf((int) bestSize.height));
                Log.e(TAG, "Set preview size to " + width + " x " + height);
                params.setPreviewSize((int) bestSize.width, (int) bestSize.height);
                params.setPictureSize((int) pictureSize.width, (int) pictureSize.height);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
                    params.setRecordingHint(true);

                List<String> FocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
                if (FocusModes != null && FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
                    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
                }
                boolean hasFlash = SevenBitsDemo.getInstance().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
                if (hasFlash) {
     //            mOpenCvCameraView.flashOn();
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                }
                List<int[]> ints = params.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
                for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("privew size", String.valueOf(ints.get(i).length));
                }
      //                    params.setPreviewFpsRange(10000,10000);
                mCamera.setParameters(params);

     //                   boolean mSurfaceConfiguring = adjustSurfaceLayoutSize(bestSize, true, width, height);

                params = mCamera.getParameters();
                GlobalArea.preview_size = params.getPreviewSize();
                mFrameWidth = params.getPreviewSize().height; //the frame width and height of the super class are used to generate the cached bitmap and they need to be the size of the resulting frame
                mFrameHeight = params.getPreviewSize().width;

                int realWidth = mFrameHeight; //the real width and height are the width and height of the frame received in onPreviewFrame ...
                int realHeight = mFrameWidth;
                if ((getLayoutParams().width == LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) && (getLayoutParams().height == LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
                    mScale = Math.min(((float) height) / mFrameHeight, ((float) width) / mFrameWidth);
                else
                    mScale = 0;

                if (mFpsMeter != null) {
                    mFpsMeter.setResolution((int) pictureSize.width, (int) pictureSize.height);
                }

                int size = mFrameWidth * mFrameHeight;
                size = size * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(params.getPreviewFormat()) / 8;
                mBuffer = new byte[size];

                mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
                mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);

                mFrameChain = new Mat[2];
                mFrameChain[0] = new Mat(realHeight + (realHeight / 2), realWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1); //the frame chane is still in landscape
                mFrameChain[1] = new Mat(realHeight + (realHeight / 2), realWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);

                AllocateCache();

                mCameraFrame = new JavaCameraFrame[2];
                mCameraFrame[0] = new JavaCameraFrame(mFrameChain[0], mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight); //the camera frame is in portrait
                mCameraFrame[1] = new JavaCameraFrame(mFrameChain[1], mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(MAGIC_TEXTURE_ID);
                    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
                } else
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);

            /* Finally we are ready to start the preview */
                Log.d(TAG, "startPreview");
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } else
                result = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

protected void releaseCamera() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

            mCamera.release();
        }
        mCamera = null;
        if (mFrameChain != null) {
            mFrameChain[0].release();
            mFrameChain[1].release();
        }
        if (mCameraFrame != null) {
            mCameraFrame[0].release();
            mCameraFrame[1].release();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean connectCamera(int width, int height) {

/* 1. We need to instantiate camera
 * 2. We need to start thread which will be getting frames
 */
/* First step - initialize camera connection */
    Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to camera");
    if (!initializeCamera(width, height))
        return false;

/* now we can start update thread */
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting processing thread");
    mStopThread = false;
    mThread = new Thread(new CameraWorker());
    mThread.start();

    return true;
}

protected void disconnectCamera() {
/* 1. We need to stop thread which updating the frames
 * 2. Stop camera and release it
 */
    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnecting from camera");
    try {
        mStopThread = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "Notify thread");
        synchronized (this) {
            this.notify();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Wating for thread");
        if (mThread != null)
            mThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mThread = null;
    }

/* Now release camera */
    releaseCamera();
}

public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera arg1) {
    synchronized (this) {
        mFrameChain[1 - mChainIdx].put(0, 0, frame);
        this.notify();
    }
    if (mCamera != null)
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
}

private class JavaCameraFrame implements CvCameraViewFrame {
    private Mat mYuvFrameData;
    private Mat mRgba;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private Mat mRotated;

    public Mat gray() {
        if (mRotated != null) mRotated.release();
        mRotated = mYuvFrameData.submat(0, mWidth, 0, mHeight); 
     //submat with reversed width and height because its done on the 
    landscape frame
        mRotated = mRotated.t();
        Core.flip(mRotated, mRotated, 1);
        return mRotated;
    }

    public Mat rgba() {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12, 4);
        if (mRotated != null) mRotated.release();
        mRotated = mRgba.t();
        Core.flip(mRotated, mRotated, 1);
        return mRotated;
    }

    public JavaCameraFrame(Mat Yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
        super();
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mYuvFrameData = Yuv420sp;
        mRgba = new Mat();
    }

    public void release() {
        mRgba.release();
        if (mRotated != null) mRotated.release();
    }
}

private class CameraWorker implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        do {
            synchronized (PortraitCameraView.this) {
                try {
                    PortraitCameraView.this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "CameraWorker interrupted", e);
                }
            }

            if (!mStopThread) {
                if (!mFrameChain[mChainIdx].empty())
                    deliverAndDrawFrame(mCameraFrame[mChainIdx]);
                mChainIdx = 1 - mChainIdx;
            }
        } while (!mStopThread);
        Log.d(TAG, "Finish processing thread");
    }


}
 }
```

So now use PortraitCameraView in your xml and java file because i have convert javacamera view in portrait mode in this class.

Comment: what is value of this line GlobalArea.preview_size = params.getPreviewSize();

Answer (score 0):

You can use setMaxFrame size function.

```
javaCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(480, 640);
```

480 is width and 640 is height. Now javacameraview is portrait.